# How to get map value by key without range action (htm/text templates)? Golang

Tags: templates, go

I try just to get map value without iteration through the map.

For example, at the moment to get the map value by key this weird way:

```
{{range $key, $value := .mymap}}
    {{if $value = "myvalue"}}
        {{template "item" .}}
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

May be there is any better way just to get map value by key? For example:

```
{{print .mymap["key"]}}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use index to get a value from a map:

```
{{index .mymap "key"}}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/XzH9gKUOMx)

Comment: Very good. I've tried the same - it didn't work - but for now it works like a charm!) Can I somehow make my statements shorter? For example: `{{if eq $val index .map "key"}}...`, instead `{{$mapVal := index .map "key"}}` and only then `{{if eq $val $mapVal}}...`. I think it's some sort of chaining.

Comment: What about long if statements? Eg: `if (1==1 && 2==2) || 3==4`. How it will looks like in templates? This is the right one `if and (eq 1 1) (eq 2 2) or (eq 3 4)` ?

Comment: If it requires separate question, I create it!)

Comment: it looks like a pile))